# Chaining navigation controllers

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller (A) with it's content view controller (B) and a view controller with modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet (C).

Well it appears (strangely) that a view controller doesn't maintain the view hierarchy the way you yourself would if you create and add a view to another view.

For example, a navigation controller (A) when presenting, does not setup (B) like this...

```
[self addChildViewController:child];
[self.view addSubview:child.view];
[child didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

... therefore, if you try to present a view controller from (B), the debug console with complain with a message like ...

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x79454a00> on <iRpImageViewerViewController: 0x81e4fc00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

The only way I know to get rid of that message is to present the photo details editor navigation controller (C) from navigation controller (A) and NOT from (A)'s content view controller (B)---the child of (A)

Is this normal, that the chain of views is mangled by navigation controllers, resulting in the warning message above, or do I just not understand how presenting views has to work, and that you can't properly present a navigation controller (C) from another navigation controllers content controller (B), but only from the parent navigation controller itself (A).

The quick and easy way to make the console warning appear is to change the last line in this code snippet from `self.parentViewController` to `self`

```
-(void)handleDoubleTapRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
    {
        NSLog(@"Double Tapped, so opening editor");
        IGCellPath *pathForCurrentCell = [self pathForCurrentCell];
        iRpImageAndMedia *imageAndMediaItem = [thePropertyImageSet objectAtIndex:pathForCurrentCell.columnIndex];
        iRpImageEditorViewController *imageEditor = [[iRpImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImageAndMediaItem:imageAndMediaItem];

        imageEditor.navigationItem.title = @"Photo Details Editor";
        imageEditor.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:imageEditor];

        navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        navController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(imageEditorDone)];
        navController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(imageEditorCancelled)];
        navController.preferredContentSize = imageEditor.view.frame.size;


        [self.parentViewController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^(void){ }];

    }
```

[image]

Comment: What is a "modal sheet view controller"? Could you try to use more exact technical terminology? Could you also show the presentation code? Even better, could you just make a new project and sketch out the structure of the whole problem (you'll only need two view controller classes, I think) and post the project so that I can try to reproduce this?

Comment: Sorry, I found the problem.  I showed a code snippet, then it occurred to me what the problem was, and I slapped my forehead so hard I fell outta my chair.

Comment: Instead of editing your question stating that you solved it, you should either delete the question or post a proper answer.

Comment: OK, will do. Thanks.